# Undo custom jQuery UI theme font style rules for select elements

Tags: css, jquery-ui

My custom css file from themeroller specifies the font-family and font-size of select elements.

This is causing trouble and I need to get those properties back to the values from the UA stylesheet.

Is there any way to set these back to the UA's values without knowing them? Or do I have to edit the css file from themeroller?

Answer (score 0):

You can just target the jquery-ui element you wish to modify using the class it registers for the element. You can grab that class using a tool such as firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools.

Example:

Changing the font-size of jquery UI's Datepicker month day elements:

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default {
  font-size:20px;
  color:pink;
}
```

You can add your overwritten css inside of your main CSS file and it will pick up your changes.

Comment: sure, overriding jui style rules with my own is perfectly straightforward. that was not the question. it was how to restore the UA stylesheet's css property values. i don't know these values when i author my own stylesheet because every UA is different. what i want is for the selects to look however selects normally look on that device. for example, in chrome on osx the default select font is Lucida Grande 11pt. that spec will likely not work well in other UAs.

Comment: @fsb mm, i'm not quite understanding your issue. Can you rephrase your question? Restore which property value?

Comment: if a web page does not specify styles or assign a stylesheet then the elements on the page are rendered using the UA's stylesheet. that stylesheet defines the browsers "default style rules" so to speak (if it is a web browser). each UA has its own "default styles". thus a select element has certain "default styles" in any given UA. now, my jui themeroller stylesheet applies styles to selects and that is a problem. my question is, how to get rid of the jui styles so that the UA defaults are in effect. do i have to delete the offending rules in jui's css file or can i do this in my own css file?